# With PHP 7, are there any speed benefits to PHAR?

Tags: php, apc, php-7, phar

I came across [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/13uwgk/phar_performance/c77kmjb/) from a few years ago discussing pro & con of PHAR in PHP deployments. One of the main issues then was lack of APC support for PHAR. Besides for large scale deployments of widely used tools, I don't see much PHAR use in the wild in end user applications.

Is the era of PHAR over? Besides deployment ease, is there any speed benefit today to using PHAR? Does PHP 7 support caching PHAR?

Update:
Today I located the following in the PHP source code, which implies that PHAR is opcode cached: [Lines 152-156](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP-7.0/ext/opcache/ZendAccelerator.c#152)

Comment: Well composer is available for download as a phar, as are many tools like phpunit, and those used for static analysis such as  phpmd and pdepend

Comment: @MarkBaker thats a benefit in regards to distribution/deployment. I am wondering more about speed. I will clarify my question test.

Comment: IMO it has been entirely supplanted by Composer.

Comment: This was the first related question, might add more details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521484/advantages-of-phar-archives-in-php?rq=1

Comment: There aren't any significant benefits to speed, or to memory usage; you're still executing the same PHP code that you would if it wasn't a phar, and it will still be opcached in the same way as a suite of files; the benefit is a single file distribution/deployment

Comment: I was always under the impression that there is a noticeable overhead when decoding a .phar vs loading php files but I don't remember where I got this feeling from...